# Deploying react portfolio website on github user page

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I was working on my portfolio and I build it using react and I thought to deploy this using GitHub pages.

So, I started deploying and I've followed pretty much every step given there ['Create React App / Deployment'](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment), but I was not able to see the desired result.

You can [Check here at `thisisnitish.github.io`](https://thisisnitish.github.io/): It deploys the README and I tried everything to fix it but it shows the same result.

You can visit the repository [at `github.com/thisisnitish/thisisnitish.github.io`](https://github.com/thisisnitish/thisisnitish.github.io).

[image: Github Pages Info]

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Since https://hisisnitish.github.io returns 404, it means nothing has been published by GitHub.

That would be because of the [configuring a publishing source for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site).

Make sure to select the branch `main`, folder `public` in order to instruct GitHub to publish your page from those elements.

The OP adds:

> there is only a root and docs folder like this

Then you might try, for testing, to generate your site in the `docs/` folder, instead of `public/`.
Or to generate it in a separate branch.

Comment: It is already there, I've added the GitHub pages info, please look at the last line in post

Comment: @NitishKumar Why not set it to the public folder: it is that folder which includes the `index.html` you want.

Comment: I've added the screenshot and there is no public folder, there is only a root and docs folder like this, if you go [Configuring a publishing source for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) similar to step 5

Comment: @NitishKumar OK. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

On your `package.json`, change the `deploy` script

```
"scripts": {
    ... (other scripts)
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b main -d build"
}
```

Moreover, do not push your entire repository on github pages. Only content of `/build` folder is important here.

Alternatively, you can build your react app locally

`npm run build`

Then upload/copy contents of `/build` (`index.html` etc.) to your repository.